# Getting ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) while training RNN

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
regressor=Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32)
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32)
```

After using `fit` method I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)
```

If anyone has any way out do help in this regard

Comment: what is `X_train`?

Comment: @NicolasGervais X_train is the part of training dataset which is feature scaled.